# General method for calculating p-values from confidence intervals?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

**Setup**

Suppose we have a random data element $X$ and an estimator $\hat \vartheta = \hat \vartheta(X)$ for a parameter $\vartheta \in \mathbb R$ of the distribution of $X$.

I’d like to generate a *p*-value for the null hypothesis $H_0: \vartheta = 0$ vs the alternative $H_1 : \vartheta \neq 0$.

Suppose we have a method of calculating valid $100 \cdot (1 - \alpha)$% confidence intervals $C_\alpha = [ \underline{C}_\alpha, \overline{C}_\alpha ]$, i.e. $\mathbb P(\vartheta \in C) = 1-\alpha$. And assume the monotonicity $C_\alpha \subseteq C_{\alpha'}$ for any $1 > \alpha > \alpha' > 0$, as well as the existence of a sufficiently small $\alpha'$ such that $0 \in C_{a'}$. Set

$$
\hat p := \sup\{\alpha'\in (0,1): 0 \in C_{\alpha'} \}
$$

to get a (candidate) *p*-value and the corresponding test $\varphi_\alpha := \mathbf 1\{\hat p<\alpha\}$, where $1$ stands for rejection of the null, while $0$ represents a failure to reject the null.

**Question**

Is $\hat p$ then a valid *p*-value? (Are arguments made for this below sound and sufficient?)

**Thoughts and arguments**

- The idea for this comes from the $100\cdot(1-\alpha)$% induced level-$\alpha$ test $\tilde \varphi_\alpha := \mathbf 1\{0 \notin C_\alpha \}$. Note that $\mathbb E_{\vartheta = 0}[\tilde \varphi_\alpha] = 1 - \mathbb P_{\vartheta = 0}(0 \in C_\alpha) = 1-(1-\alpha) = \alpha$, so $\tilde\varphi_\alpha$ has the level $\alpha$.
- The tests $\varphi$ and $\tilde \varphi$ yield the same decision for any fixed $\alpha$, i.e. $\varphi_\alpha \equiv \tilde \varphi_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

  *Proof:* Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then

  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \varphi_\alpha = 1 
  &\iff \sup\{\alpha'\in (0,1): 0 \in C_{\alpha'} \} < \alpha \\
  &\iff 0 \notin C_\alpha \\
  &\iff \tilde \varphi_\alpha = 1.
  \end{aligned}
  $$

  $\square$
- Under the same assumptions, it holds that $\hat p \overset{H_0}{\sim} U(0,1)$. Indeed,

  $$\begin{aligned}
  \mathbb P_{\vartheta = 0}(\hat p < \alpha ) 
  &= \mathbb P_{\vartheta = 0}(\varphi = 1)
  = \mathbb P_{\vartheta = 0}(\tilde \varphi = 1) = \mathbb E_{\vartheta = 0}[\tilde \varphi] = \alpha.
  \end{aligned}$$

  This is what we expect from a valid *p*-value.
- ***Motivation:*** I’d like to use such *p*-values as inputs in a multiple testing correction. Indeed, if my reasoning above is correct, then $\hat p$ satisfies condition in (3) for a *p*-value in this [summary of multiple testing](https://home.uchicago.edu/%7Eamshaikh/webfiles/multiplereview.pdf) by Romano, Shaikh, and Wolf.